# Extending session via init.php

Tags: php, session, init

I have a social network that I'm trying to make the user session as long as possible. We just recently switched to a new server, and before that, `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60*60*24*7*2);` enabled a two week or so log in, even when a browser was closed and re-opened.

For some reason this is not working anymore and the session is lasting only a short while.

My questions is what could that be besides maxlifetime and does it have to do with some default configuration on the new server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that ini_set() is switched off on the new server for security reasons. If this is the case you would have to edit the php.ini configuration file to be able to change the maximum lifetime of a session.

Did you set up the server or are you renting it? If you are renting, it's very likely that you aren't allowed to make changes like this. In this case, I suggest using a cookie to track user sessions.

Edit: You can check if you have access to change ini settings by looking at the return value from ini_set(). It will return false on failure.